# Pydev and Pylons inside virtual environment, auto completion won’t work

Tags: python, pylons, pydev, virtualenv

I have Pydev installed and running without problem with Python 2.6. I installed Pylons 0.9.7 RC 4 into virtual environment, then configured new interpreter to pint into virtual environment and this one is used for pylons project. My problem is that code auto completion does not work for a classes from base library (one that are installed with base python installation), and it works without any problem with classes from virtual environment.

TIA

Comment: auto competition means you are competing with some other code for the processor and memory? Don't you mean "completion"?

Comment: You are correct; I need help with code COMPLETITION. This typo was caused partially be spelling checker I use, partially by a fact that English in not my first language.

Comment: The point is not to comment @Bob Rock, the point is to fix your question.  Please edit your question to use the word "COMPLETION".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

perhaps [this](http://www.nabble.com/-pydev---Users--Multiple-Interpreters-td17679628.html) or [this](http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/browse_thread/thread/916ab8ac6c2ae746?fwc=1&pli=1) would help

*BTW: I guess that this is the correct behavior, this interpreter uses only the packages that are installed withing the virtualenv (this is the whole intent and purpose of the virtualenv isn't it?)*